# Couchbase SearchQuery doesn't return rows when the matchPhrase value is "all"

Tags: java, full-text-search, couchbase

I am using couchbase java-client version 2.5.4 and jdk 1.8. Couchbase SearchQuery doesn't return values when match phrase is "all".

users:

```
firstname       lastname    age    gender 
Ani             Mary        12     Female
John            William     16     Male
Rohan           all         12     Male
John            Sam         13     Male
```

When I query the following query in couchbase cluster UI,

```
select * from users where lastname ="all" and firstname="rohan";
```

it returns a row but it doesn't return a value when I use MatchPhrase query.

```
SearchQueryResult result = bucket.query(new SearchQuery("users_fts",
SearchQuery.matchPhrase("all")).fields("lastname"));
```

The result must be like the following, users:

```
firstname       lastname    age    gender 
Rohan           all         12     Male
```

FTS index:

```
{
  "type": "fulltext-index",
  "name": "users_fts",
  "uuid": "4dcbdd4c3399403a",
  "sourceType": "couchbase",
  "sourceName": "users",
  "sourceUUID": "199658ae21c89cd0c33add8325ca88aa",
  "planParams": {
    "maxPartitionsPerPIndex": 171
  },
  "params": {
    "doc_config": {
      "mode": "type_field",
      "type_field": "type"
    },
    "mapping": {
      "default_analyzer": "standard",
      "default_datetime_parser": "dateTimeOptional",
      "default_field": "_all",
      "default_mapping": {
        "dynamic": true,
        "enabled": true
      },
      "default_type": "_default",
      "index_dynamic": true,
      "store_dynamic": false
    },
    "store": {
      "kvStoreName": "mossStore"
    }
  },
  "sourceParams": {}
}
```

How to write a code to get this result with string "all" in couchbase SearchQuery?

Comment: Reserved keywords usually aren't ignored silently.

Comment: Ok. but its not returning result value as well as error.. :(

Comment: Would you please share the FTS index you've created?

Comment: @MatthewGroves I have updated my question with FTS index. Kindly have a look into this and provide yours thoughts.

Comment: any inputs here really appreciated.